# Changing Default Retention Policy Length

Tags: influxdb

I have been saving data in my InfluxDB instance with a Default retention policy with a DURATION of 720h (30 days). I have recently altered the same retention policy to keep the data for INF (0s). I was expecting to have issues querying the data stored under the old RP duration ( as explained here https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/troubleshooting/frequently_encountered_issues/#missing-data-after-creating-a-new-default-retention-policy) but haven't had any issues.

Should I expect to see issues or will my data just be kept indefinitely?

I altered the RP via the `ALTER` command and everything worked correctly however having a few minutes and a few new data points I have not had any issue with missing data.

I expected it to give me issues finding older data.

Before:

```
name                     duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----                     -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen                  0s       168h0m0s           1        false
default_retention_policy 720h0m0s 24h0m0s            1        true
one_day                  24h0m0s  1h0m0s             1        false
```

After `ALTER RETENTION POLICY default_retention_policy on defaultdb DURATION INF`:

```
name                     duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----                     -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen                  0s       168h0m0s           1        false
default_retention_policy 0s       168h0m0s           1        true
one_day                  24h0m0s  1h0m0s             1        false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. That caveat is for when you create a new default retention policy. Using ALTER should keep you working just fine

Comment: Thanks Rawkode! I haven't seen any issues yet since making the change!